# Any way to get details of who Created/Modified Cloud Pages?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I see there is no option to view this on UI and no SQL data views to get details of a specific page.

Answer (score 1):

You can see when it was created but the cloud pages do not logged modified dates in the UI. You will have to contact support to check the server logs

Comment: Thanks! Wanted to check if there is any other alternate way to get details without contacting support. But found that's the only option :(